# Facing scroll bar size issue with 'TELTree' Control in Microsoft Server 2012 OS

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, windows-server-2012

I am working on an delphi application.

while unit testing of the same I come to know that the size of a `scroll bar` is getting changed while running on the different OS.

The Scenario is:

When I am running the application in `Windows 8 OS` the `scroll bar` size is normal as `17px`.

But when the same application where run on `Windows Server 2012 OS` the scroll bar size is getting changed to `4px`.

I am getting confused why this is happening with the application.

I am using  `TElTree` control in which I am facing `scroll bar` issue.

Find the snaps of the result of the scroll bars:

[image: Scroll bar in Windows 8]

[image: Scroll Bar in Windows Server 2012 OS]

Please let me know why such a thing is happening with the application.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @TLama So, do you have any suggestion for me?
and is it possible that the scrollbar size can be different for different os?

Comment: Nope, sorry. I don't have ElPack. And yes, the scrollbar size varies not only with OS version, but also with the selected theme and some registry settings, but all that is system wide, for all applications. I cannot speak for ElPack, but for LMD Tools (from the same vendor) and they are having their own scrollbars, which are system independent; or at least they can render by the selected theme, but in metrics that you set. If I were you, I would ask vendor about this issue.